# Difference in Start and End times grouping by hour

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle10g, group-by, date-arithmetic

My table has info similar to below

```
Emp  Date       START_TIME            END_TIME             Code     Minutes
---  --------   -------------------   -------------------  ----     -------
 E1  11/1/2012  11/1/2012 6:55:00 AM  11/1/2012 7:01:00 AM  C1       6
 E1  11/1/2012  11/1/2012 6:57:00 AM  11/1/2012 8:01:00 AM  C2       64
 E2  11/1/2012  11/1/2012 6:57:00 AM  11/1/2012 8:00:00 AM  C2       63
 E1  11/2/2012  11/2/2012 7:35:00 AM  11/2/2012 8:01:00 AM  C1       26
```

Expected Output is

```
Date       Code  Range                        Minutes
---------  ----  -----------------------      ------- 
11/1/2012   C1   6:30:00 AM-7:00:00 AM           5
11/1/2012   C1   7:00:00 AM-7:30:00 AM           1
11/1/2012   C2   6:30:00 AM-7:00:00 AM           6   
11/1/2012   C2   7:00:00 AM-7:30:00 AM           60
11/1/2012   C2   7:30:00 AM-8:00:00 AM           60
11/1/2012   C2   8:00:00 AM-8:30:00 AM           1
11/2/2012   C1   7:30:00 AM-8:00:00 AM           25
11/2/2012   C1   8:00:00 AM-8:30:00 AM           1
```

Leaving out Emp field, I want to group by date, and code with total time spent in a span of 30 minutes each. And the *limitation I have is to achieve this using select statements i.e. only through SQL queries coz PL/SQL is not allowed*. Thanks in advance!

Comment: @mcalex I first tried to find out the total minutes spent on an hour and I grouped by start_time field, to_char(start_time,'HH24') to get wrong results. I know that the query should include some calculation but lacks sufficient knowledge on how to extract the desired result..

Comment: second and third line - there are more than 64 minutes : AM to PM.

Comment: Do you have the ranges defined in another table?

Comment: @ChristofferLette Nope! Actually I need to find out for every 30 minutes in a day, so 48(24*2) ranges in total. The source table is what all I have and if a 30 minute range does not exist in it, it is not needed in the output.

Comment: The question is clear.  Needs just some time to get a good answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am pretty sure this can be cleaned up, and made more legible and more efficient as Oracle is not one of my strong suits, but it works and should give an idea of how to accomplish the task.

The key here is joining to a list of numbers to break up your records into half hour periods.

```
SELECT  "Date",
        "Code",
        "RangeStart" + ((r - 1) / 48.0) AS "RangeStart",
        "RangeStart" + (r / 48.0) AS "RangeEnd",
        SUM(CASE WHEN r = 1 THEN "StartMinutes"
                WHEN "END_TIME" >= "RangeStart" + ((r - 1) / 48.0) AND "END_TIME" < "RangeStart" + (r / 48.0) THEN "EndMinutes"
                ELSE 30 
            END) AS "TotalMinutes"
FROM    (   SELECT  "Emp",
                    "Date",
                    "START_TIME",
                    "END_TIME",
                    "Code",
                    CASE WHEN EXTRACT(MINUTE from "START_TIME") > 30 THEN 60 ELSE 30 END - EXTRACT(MINUTE from "START_TIME") AS "StartMinutes",
                    EXTRACT(MINUTE from END_TIME) - CASE WHEN EXTRACT(MINUTE from "END_TIME") > 30 THEN 30 ELSE 0 END AS "EndMinutes",
                    "START_TIME" - (EXTRACT(MINUTE from "START_TIME") - CASE WHEN EXTRACT(MINUTE from "START_TIME") > 30 THEN 30 ELSE 0 END) / (60 * 24.0) AS "RangeStart"
            FROM    T
        ) T
        INNER JOIN
        (   SELECT  Rownum r
            FROM    dual
            CONNECT BY Rownum <= 100
        ) r
            ON "END_TIME" > ("RangeStart" + ((r - 1) / 48.0))
GROUP BY "Date", "Code", "RangeStart" + ((r - 1) / 48.0), "RangeStart" + (r / 48.0)
ORDER BY "Code", "Date", "RangeStart";
```

**[EXAMPLE ON SQL FIDDLE](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!4/828e5/14)**

Comment: That almost worked but if you check in Fiddle, the number of minutes for code C2 in range 7:30 to 8:00 on Nov 01 is 30 instead of 60!

Comment: Oops. It was to do with the `BETWEEN` in the case statement. I have corrected this now so it gives 60 for the relevant range.

Answer (score 2):

a solution involving the model clause.

first lets compute the amount of 30 minute blocks we need per entry.

```
SQL> select emp, start_time, end_time, code,
  2                      trunc(start_time, 'mi')
  3                      - (mod(to_char(trunc(start_time, 'mi'), 'mi'), 30) / 1440) start_block,
  4                      ceil(2*24*(end_time-(trunc(start_time, 'mi')
  5                      - (mod(to_char(trunc(start_time, 'mi'), 'mi'), 30) / 1440)))) blocks
  6                 from tab f
  7  /

EM START_TIME             END_TIME               CO START_BLOCK                BLOCKS
-- ---------------------- ---------------------- -- ---------------------- ----------
E1 11/01/2012 06:55:00 am 11/01/2012 07:01:00 am C1 11/01/2012 06:30:00 am          2
E1 11/01/2012 06:57:00 am 11/01/2012 08:01:00 am C2 11/01/2012 06:30:00 am          4
E2 11/01/2012 06:57:00 am 11/01/2012 08:00:00 am C2 11/01/2012 06:30:00 am          3
E1 11/02/2012 07:35:00 am 11/02/2012 08:01:00 am C1 11/02/2012 07:30:00 am          2
```

now, we generate rows to break this into 30 minute periods using the model clause.

```
SQL> with foo as (select rownum id, emp, start_time, end_time, code,
  2                      trunc(start_time, 'mi')
  3                      - (mod(to_char(trunc(start_time, 'mi'), 'mi'), 30) / 1440) start_block,
  4                      ceil(2*24*(end_time-(trunc(start_time, 'mi')
  5                      - (mod(to_char(trunc(start_time, 'mi'), 'mi'), 30) / 1440)))) blocks
  6                 from tab f)
  7  select trunc(start_time) thedate, code, emp, range, minutes
  8    from foo
  9   model partition by(id)
 10         dimension by(0 as f)
 11         measures(code, emp, start_time, end_time, start_block, blocks,
 12                  sysdate as start_range,
 13                  sysdate as end_range,
 14                  cast(0 as number) minutes,
 15                  cast('' as varchar2(50)) range)
 16         rules (start_range [for f from 0 to blocks[0]-1  increment 1]  = start_block[0] + (30*cv(f)/1440),
 17                end_range[any]  =  start_range[cv()] + (30/1440),
 18                code[any]  =  code[0],
 19                emp[any]   =  emp[0],
 20                start_time[any]  =  start_time[0],
 21                end_time[any]  =  end_time[0],
 22                range [any] = to_char(start_range[cv()], 'dd/mm/yyyy hh:mi:ss am') || ' - ' || to_char(end_range[cv()], 'dd/mm/yyyy hh24:mi:ss am'),
 23                minutes [any]   = case
 24                                    when start_time[0] between start_range[cv()] and end_range[cv()]
 25                                    then 1440 *(end_range[cv()] - start_time[0])
 26                                    when end_time[0] between start_range[cv()] and end_range[cv()]
 27                                    then 1440 *(end_time[0] - start_range[cv()])
 28                                    else 1440 * (end_range[cv()] - start_range[cv()])
 29                                  end );

CO EM RANGE                                                 MINUTES
-- -- -------------------------------------------------- ----------
C2 E2 11/01/2012 06:30:00 am - 11/01/2012 07:00:00 am             3
C2 E2 11/01/2012 07:00:00 am - 11/01/2012 07:30:00 am            30
C2 E2 11/01/2012 07:30:00 am - 11/01/2012 08:00:00 am            30
C1 E1 11/01/2012 06:30:00 am - 11/01/2012 07:00:00 am             5
C1 E1 11/01/2012 07:00:00 am - 11/01/2012 07:30:00 am             1
C1 E1 11/02/2012 07:30:00 am - 11/02/2012 08:00:00 am            25
C1 E1 11/02/2012 08:00:00 am - 11/02/2012 08:30:00 am             1
C2 E1 11/01/2012 06:30:00 am - 11/01/2012 07:00:00 am             3
C2 E1 11/01/2012 07:00:00 am - 11/01/2012 07:30:00 am            30
C2 E1 11/01/2012 07:30:00 am - 11/01/2012 08:00:00 am            30
C2 E1 11/01/2012 08:00:00 am - 11/01/2012 08:30:00 am             1

11 rows selected.
```

so we are partitioning by:

```
partition by(id)
```

ie by a unique reference. then we are going to generate rows with our dimension

```
dimension by(0 as f)
```

in conjuction with part of the rules:

```
for f from 0 to blocks[0]-1  increment 1
```

so the start_range column is generated with 
start_range [for f from 0 to blocks[0]-1  increment 1]  = start_block[0] + (30*cv(f)/1440),

start_block[0] is in the first query, eg:

```
EM START_TIME             END_TIME               CO START_BLOCK                BLOCKS
-- ---------------------- ---------------------- -- ---------------------- ----------
E1 11/01/2012 06:55:00 am 11/01/2012 07:01:00 am C1 11/01/2012 06:30:00 am          2
```

so for this row, it evaluates to

```
start_range[0 to 1] = 11/01/2012 06:30:00 am + (30minutes * the value of f)
```

i.e.

```
start_range[0] = 11/01/2012 06:30:00 am + (30min*0) = 11/01/2012 06:30:00 am
start_range[1] = 11/01/2012 06:30:00 am + (30min*1) = 11/01/2012 07:00:00 am
```

the rest is pretty straight forward:

```
end_range[any]  =  start_range[cv()] + (30/1440),
```

means that for `end-range` on the current row, we take `start_range` and add  30 minutes.

the `range` column is a concatenation of start_range and end_range:

```
range [any] = to_char(start_range[cv()], 'dd/mm/yyyy hh:mi:ss am') || ' - ' || to_char(end_range[cv()], 'dd/mm/yyyy hh24:mi:ss am'),
```

finally in order to calc minutes in that range:

```
minutes [any]   = case
                    when start_time[0] between start_range[cv()] and end_range[cv()]
                    then 1440 *(end_range[cv()] - start_time[0])
                    when end_time[0] between start_range[cv()] and end_range[cv()]
                    then 1440 *(end_time[0] - start_range[cv()])
                    else 1440 * (end_range[cv()] - start_range[cv()])
                  end );
```

1. if start_time sits in the range, take the end of the range - start
   time
2. if end_time sits in the range, take the end_time - start of the range
3. otherwise its end_range - start_range.

1440 just gets the answer as minutes.

now we can just group that all up:

```
SQL> with foo as (select rownum id, emp, start_time, end_time, code,
  2                      trunc(start_time, 'mi')
  3                      - (mod(to_char(trunc(start_time, 'mi'), 'mi'), 30) / 1440) start_block,
  4                      ceil(2*24*(end_time-(trunc(start_time, 'mi')
  5                      - (mod(to_char(trunc(start_time, 'mi'), 'mi'), 30) / 1440)))) blocks
  6                 from tab f)
  7  select thedate, code, range, sum(minutes) minutes
  8    from (select trunc(start_time) thedate, code, emp, range, minutes
  9            from foo
 10           model partition by(id)
 11                 dimension by(0 as f)
 12                 measures(code, emp, start_time, end_time, start_block, blocks,
 13                          sysdate as start_range,
 14                          sysdate as end_range,
 15                          cast(0 as number) minutes,
 16                          cast('' as varchar2(50)) range)
 17                 rules (start_range [for f from 0 to blocks[0]-1  increment 1]  = start_block[0] + (30*cv(f)/1440),
 18                        code[any]  =  code[0],
 19                        emp[any]  =  emp[0],
 20                        end_range[any]  =  start_range[cv()] + (30/1440),
 21                        start_time[any]  =  start_time[0],
 22                        end_time[any]  =  end_time[0],
 23                        range [any] = to_char(start_range[cv()], 'dd/mm/yyyy hh:mi:ss am') || ' - ' || to_char(end_range[cv()], 'dd/mm/yyyy hh24:mi:ss am'),
 24                        minutes [any]   = case
 25                                            when start_time[0] between start_range[cv()] and end_range[cv()]
 26                                            then 1440 *(end_range[cv()] - start_time[0])
 27                                            when end_time[0] between start_range[cv()] and end_range[cv()]
 28                                            then 1440 *(end_time[0] - start_range[cv()])
 29                                            else 1440 * (end_range[cv()] - start_range[cv()])
 30                                          end ))
 31   group by thedate, code, range
 32   order by thedate, code, range;

THEDATE    CO RANGE                                                 MINUTES
---------- -- -------------------------------------------------- ----------
11/01/2012 C1 11/01/2012 06:30:00 am - 11/01/2012 07:00:00 am             5
11/01/2012 C1 11/01/2012 07:00:00 am - 11/01/2012 07:30:00 am             1
11/01/2012 C2 11/01/2012 06:30:00 am - 11/01/2012 07:00:00 am             6
11/01/2012 C2 11/01/2012 07:00:00 am - 11/01/2012 07:30:00 am            60
11/01/2012 C2 11/01/2012 07:30:00 am - 11/01/2012 08:00:00 am            60
11/01/2012 C2 11/01/2012 08:00:00 am - 11/01/2012 08:30:00 am             1
11/02/2012 C1 11/02/2012 07:30:00 am - 11/02/2012 08:00:00 am            25
11/02/2012 C1 11/02/2012 08:00:00 am - 11/02/2012 08:30:00 am             1
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's another solution (it's not very elegant and uses hard-coded date literals to obtain the boundaries for the buckets - should probably be replaced by a sub-query to obtain them):

```
  with v_data as (
    select 1 pk, 'E1' emp, to_date('2012-11-01', 'YYYY-MM-DD') as date1, to_date('2012-11-01 06:55:00', 'YYYY-MM-DD hh24:mi:ss') as start_time, to_date('2012-11-01 07:01:00', 'YYYY-MM-DD hh24:mi:ss') as end_time, 'C1' as code, 6 as minutes from dual union all 
    select 2 pk, 'E1' emp, to_date('2012-11-01', 'YYYY-MM-DD') as date1, to_date('2012-11-01 06:57:00', 'YYYY-MM-DD hh24:mi:ss') as start_time, to_date('2012-11-01 08:01:00', 'YYYY-MM-DD hh24:mi:ss') as end_time, 'C2' as code, 64 as minutes from dual union all 
    select 3 pk, 'E2' emp, to_date('2012-11-01', 'YYYY-MM-DD') as date1, to_date('2012-11-01 06:57:00', 'YYYY-MM-DD hh24:mi:ss') as start_time, to_date('2012-11-01 08:00:00', 'YYYY-MM-DD hh24:mi:ss') as end_time, 'C2' as code, 63 as minutes from dual union all 
    select 4 pk, 'E1' emp, to_date('2012-11-02', 'YYYY-MM-DD') as date1, to_date('2012-11-02 07:35:00', 'YYYY-MM-DD hh24:mi:ss') as start_time, to_date('2012-11-02 08:01:00', 'YYYY-MM-DD hh24:mi:ss') as end_time, 'C1' as code, 26 as minutes from dual), 
v_buckets as (          
  select 
    to_date('2012-11-01', 'YYYY-MM-DD') + (rownum-1)/48 as bucket_start,
    to_date('2012-11-01', 'YYYY-MM-DD') + rownum/48 as bucket_end  
    from dual
  connect by rownum <96
)
select v3.date1, v3.bucket_start, v3.bucket_end, v3.code, sum(v3.time_spent_in_bucket) as minutes 
from (
select v2.*, (least(end_time, bucket_end) - greatest(start_time, bucket_start))*1440 as time_spent_in_bucket from 
(
select buck.*,
       v1.*
  from v_buckets buck
  join v_data v1 
    on (
       -- time slot completely contained in one bucket
        (v1.start_time >= buck.bucket_start and v1.start_time < buck.bucket_end and
        v1.end_time >= buck.bucket_start and v1.end_time < buck.bucket_end)
       -- time slot starts in bucket, expands to next bucket
        or (v1.start_time >= buck.bucket_start and v1.start_time < buck.bucket_end and
        v1.end_time >= buck.bucket_end)
       -- time slot started in previous bucket, ends in this bucket)
        or (v1.start_time < buck.bucket_start and v1.end_time > buck.bucket_start and
        v1.end_time <= buck.bucket_end)
       -- time slot began in previous bucket, expands to next bucket
       or (v1.start_time < buck.bucket_start and v1.end_time >= buck.bucket_end) 
        )
) v2
) v3 
where start_time is not null
group by date1, bucket_start, bucket_end, code
order by bucket_start, code
```

Answer (score 1):

This is my try:

```
select trunc(trunc_start) as datetime, code, range , sum(duration) minutes
from (
select code, end_time, start_time, TRUNC_START , 
  to_char(trunc_start,'hh:mi:ss AM')||'-'||to_char(trunc_start+1/48,'hh:mi:ss AM') as range,
  case 
    when end_time-trunc_start between 0 and 1/48 then (end_time-trunc_start)*1440 
    when start_time-trunc_start between 0 and 1/48 then (trunc_start-start_time)*1440+30
    else 30 
  end as duration
from(
  select  s.*, n , 
  trunc(start_time) + trunc((start_time-trunc(start_time))*48)/48 + (n-1)/48 as trunc_start
  from s
  join (select level n from dual connect by level <=48) a
  on n-2 <= (end_time-start_time)*100
  )b
)
where trunc_start < end_time --eliminating fake intervals
group by code, trunc(trunc_start), range
order by 1, 3
;
```

sorry for the `where` :)

[SQLFIDDLE](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/12d94/63)

Comment: This is the easiest one to understand and it worked like a charm! you're awesome! :)

Answer (score -1):

Here's some general example of ranges for you:

```
SELECT job
  , sum(decode(greatest(sal,2999), least(sal,6000), 1, 0)) "Range 3000-6000"
  , sum(decode(greatest(sal,1000), least(sal,2999), 1, 0)) "Range 1000-3000"
  , sum(decode(greatest(sal,0),    least(sal,999), 1, 0))  "Range 0-1000"
  FROM scott.emp
GROUP BY  job
/
```

Comment: How can this be an answer? I have to find out the sum(minutes) grouped by every code in a span/range of 30 minutes each in a day. Please look at the Expected Output!

Comment: The example may be useful but the above text over it is not an answer.